# How to sort Listbox Items?

Tags: windows-phone-7, sorting, listbox

I was just wondering if there was a way to sort the items in a listbox e.g. alphabetically descending, ascending? Soo far this is my code which basically adds files into the listbox:

```
 Dim Storage As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    Dim directory As String = "./MyNote/SavedNotes/*.*"
    Dim filenames As String() = Storage.GetFileNames(directory)
    Dim dataSource As New List(Of SampleData)()
    For Each filename As String In filenames
        Dim ISF As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
        Dim FS As IsolatedStorageFileStream = ISF.OpenFile("MyNote/SavedNotes/" & filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Using SR As New StreamReader(FS)
            Dim FTime As String = GetRelativeTime(Storage.GetCreationTime("MyNote/SavedNotes/" & filename).ToString)
            Dim DATESS As String = SR.ReadLine
            Dim ReadName As String = SR.ReadLine
            dataSource.Add(New SampleData() With {.FileNameX = filename, .Description = ReadName, .FileTime = FTime})
        End Using
    Next
    SavedNotesList.ItemsSource = dataSource
```

I was just wondering how i can sort the added items alphabetically ascending? can someone help me? i heard that a observerablecollection or some sort is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily do by

```
 Dim query As IEnumerable(Of SampleData) = _
            datasource.OrderBy(Function(SampleData) s.FileNameX )
```

Comment: hey thanks for that but what's the "pets"? am i supposed to replace the code you provided me with: ` SavedNotesList.ItemsSource = dataSource` or is it a seperate option?

Comment: alright so i managed to update that code a little bit so that it's: ` Dim query As IEnumerable(Of SampleData) = dataSource.OrderBy(Function(SampleData) SampleData.FileNameX)` but is it supposed to be ascending or descending? im a bit confused

Comment: Oh i just figured it out Thanks a bunch!